# CSS problem <li> height

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, html-lists

Please check this one:

http://jsfiddle.net/sasindu555/nNyxk/8/

You can see **Description**, **Features** and **Contact Details** `<li>` tags are not fully filled with the background color. Please help me to solve this.

---

Here is the CSS:

```
#h-spacer {
    width:auto;
    height:1px;
    clear:both;
    font-size:0
}
#property-details {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    border-left:solid #65C6ED 1px;
    border-top:solid #65C6ED 1px
}
#property-details ul {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    border-bottom:solid #65C6ED 1px
}
#property-details ul li {
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    list-style-image:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:left;
    padding:2px 5px;
    color:#4f4f4f;
    line-height:1.8em;
    font-size:11px;
    border-right:solid #65C6ED 1px
}
#property-details ul li.title {
    width:140px;
    font-weight:600;
    background:#e5f8ff
}
#property-details ul li.data {
    width:360px;
    font-weight:normal;
    background:#f1fbff
}

#property-details-sub.sub {
    margin:0 auto;
    height:auto;
    width:369px;
    padding:0px;
    border-left:solid #65C6ED 1px;
    border-top:solid #65C6ED 1px
}
#property-details-sub ul {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    border-bottom:solid #65C6ED 1px
}
#property-details-sub ul li {
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    list-style-image:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:left;
    padding:2px 5px;
    color:#4f4f4f;
    line-height:1.8em;
    font-size:11px;
    border-right:solid #65C6ED 1px
}
#property-details-sub ul li.title-sub {
    width:100px;
    font-weight:600;
    background:#e5f8ff
}
#property-details-sub ul li.data-sub {
    width:247px;
    font-weight:normal;
    background:#f1fbff
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="property-details">
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Category</li>
        <li class="data">House for Sale</li>
        <div id="h-spacer"></div>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Reference Number</li>
        <li class="data">10066</li>
        <div id="h-spacer"></div>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Published On</li>
        <li class="data">June 07,2011</li>
        <div id="h-spacer"></div>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Description</li>
        <li class="data">House for Sale Akuregoda House Built in a 12.5 Perch Land Located at 200m away from The Akuregoda Main Road With 6 Rooms, 3 Bath rooms, Living Room, Dining Room Surrounded By walls With an Annex is Available for Sale at Rs 42 (Negotiable) 4.2 Million </li>
        <div id="h-spacer"></div>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Location - District</li>
        <li class="data">Colombo</li>
        <div id="h-spacer"></div>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Location - City</li>
        <li class="data">Akuregoda</li>
        <div id="h-spacer"></div>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Property address</li>
        <li class="data">Akuregoda, Colombo</li>
        <div id="h-spacer"></div>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Number of Rooms</li>
        <li class="data">6</li>
        <div id="h-spacer"></div>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Number of Floors</li>
        <li class="data">2</li>
        <div id="h-spacer"></div>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Floor Area </li>
        <li class="data">1200</li>
        <div id="h-spacer"></div>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Land Area </li>
        <li class="data">Acres : 0 / Perches :28.00</li>
        <div id="h-spacer"></div>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Selling Price </li>
        <li class="data">Rs. 4,200,000.00</li>
        <div id="h-spacer"></div>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Features </li>
        <li class="data">    » Air Conditioned<br />
            » Cable TV<br />
            » Garage<br />
            » Hot Water<br />
            » Internet<br />
            » Parapet Wall<br />
            » Pipe Bourne Water<br />
            » Telephone Line<br />
            » Veranda<br /></li>
        <div id="h-spacer"></div>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Property Availablity</li>
        <li class="data">Immediatly available</li>
        <div id="h-spacer"></div>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Advertisment expires</li>
        <li class="data">In 10 days</li>
        <div id="h-spacer"></div>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Contact Details</li>
        <li id="property-details-sub" class="sub">
            <ul>
                <li class="title-sub">Name</li>
                <li class="data-sub">Sasindu Hewage</li>
                <div id="h-spacer"></div>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li class="title-sub">Address</li>
                <li class="data-sub">627, Thalangama South</li>
                <div id="h-spacer"></div>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li class="title-sub">Contact number</li>
                <li class="data-sub">+94779559589</li>
                <div id="h-spacer"></div>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li class="title-sub">Inquiry via Email</li>
                <li class="data-sub">Send an inquiry</li>
                <div id="h-spacer"></div>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li class="title-sub">Skype Id</li>
                <li class="data-sub">sasindu</li>
                <div id="h-spacer"></div>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <div id="h-spacer"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you're missing the intended use of the HTML tags there. You should be using a `<dl>` definition list (although a table will be easier to style, if you want it displayed like you're trying). The "features" section should be an `<ul>` unordered list.

Comment: @Tak: Definitely a table at least. Although I think the designs of old have scared people from using tables entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to set the background color of the li.tittle not in li but set it to ul.
Then problem remains for the border-right property of the li, so move this border-right property to #property-details ul li.data item and change it to border-left.

So, I suggest these changes:

```css
#property-details ul { 
    background-color: #E5F8FF
}
#property-details ul li.data { 
    border-right:solid #65C6ED 1px;
    border-left:solid #65C6ED 1px;
}
/* remove this from your css:
   #property-details ul li {
       border-right: solid #65C6ED 1px;
   }
*/
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nNyxk/21/

Comment: That also works, but you have a similar problem to my solution, in that the height of the right column must be greater than that of the left column. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/nNyxk/22/

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using lists? The proper elements to use here are definition lists (`<dl>`). You can even use tables for this (it is *tabular data*).

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
body {
    font-size:11px;
    margin:1em;
    color:#4f4f4f
}
ul {
    list-style-position:inside
}
#property-details {
    background:#e5f8ff;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#65c6ed;
    border-width:1px 1px 0;
    line-height:1.8em
}
#property-details dl {
    border-bottom:1px solid #65c6ed;
    position:relative
}
#property-details dt, #property-details dd {
    padding:2px 5px
}
#property-details dt {
    font-weight:600;
    width:140px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0
}
#property-details dd {
    background:#f1fbff;
    position:relative;
    left:140px;
    margin-right:140px;
    border-left:1px solid #65c6ed
}
#property-details .sub {
    padding:0
}
#property-details .sub dl:last-child {
    border:0
}
```

**HTML** (with definition lists):

```
<div id="property-details">
    <dl>
        <dt>Category</dt>
        <dd>House for Sale</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>Reference Number</dt>
        <dd>10066</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>Published On</dt>
        <dd>June 07,2011</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>Description</dt>
        <dd>House for Sale Akuregoda House Built in a 12.5 Perch Land Located at 200m away from The Akuregoda Main Road With 6 Rooms, 3 Bath rooms, Living Room, Dining Room Surrounded By walls With an Annex is Available for Sale at Rs 42 (Negotiable) 4.2 Million </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>Location - District</dt>
        <dd>Colombo</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>Location - City</dt>
        <dd>Akuregoda</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>Property address</dt>
        <dd>Akuregoda, Colombo</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>Number of Rooms</dt>
        <dd>6</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>Number of Floors</dt>
        <dd>2</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>Floor Area </dt>
        <dd>1200</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>Land Area </dt>
        <dd>Acres : 0 / Perches :28.00</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>Selling Price </dt>
        <dd>Rs. 4,200,000.00</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>Features </dt>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li>Air Conditioned</li>
                <li>Cable TV</li>
                <li>Garage</li>
                <li>Hot Water</li>
                <li>Internet</li>
                <li>Parapet Wall</li>
                <li>Pipe Bourne Water</li>
                <li>Telephone Line</li>
                <li>Veranda</li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>Property Availablity</dt>
        <dd>Immediatly available</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>Advertisment expires</dt>
        <dd>In 10 days</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>Contact Details</dt>
        <dd class="sub">
            <dl>
                <dt>Name</dt>
                <dd>Sasindu Hewage</dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt>Address</dt>
                <dd>627, Thalangama South</dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt>Contact number</dt>
                <dd>+94779559589</dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt>Inquiry via Email</dt>
                <dd>Send an inquiry</dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt>Skype Id</dt>
                <dd>sasindu</dd>
            </dl>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

And all your spacers are gone...

Comment: thanx brother. I never been known about `<dl>`. thanks for your answer

Comment: I have problem with this. please check http://jsfiddle.net/sasindu555/5ETKa/1/ What will happen when right side height is less than left side height ?